# c++ Stop Enemy Sprites Moving Over Each Other

Tags: c++

I'm making a 2d game and I'm trying to stop enemy sprites moving over each other. I've implemented the following method that is supposed to check that enemies are not overlapping, then move one of them back in the direction they came. However this method seems to crash my game as only one enemy is ever rendered.

This is my check method:

```
size = enemys.size();
for (int i = 0; i<size; i++){
    double x = enemys[i].getEnemyX();
    double y = enemys[i].getEnemyY();
    for (int s = 1; s<size; s++){
        double enemyX = enemys[s].getEnemyX();
        double enemyY = enemys[s].getEnemyY();
        if (x >= enemyX-5.0 && x <= enemyX+5.0 && y >= enemyY-5.0 &&  y <= enemyY + 5.0){
            double xDir = x - enemyX;
            double yDir = y - enemyY;
            double hyp = sqrt(xDir*xDir + yDir*yDir);
            xDir /= hyp;
            yDir /= hyp;
            x -= xDir * 5;
            y -= yDir * 5;
            enemys[s].setEnemyCoord(x,y);
        }
    }
}*
```

Comment: Your life would be less painful if you defined a structure with two elements, one for each dimension, to represent an object's location, rather than using 2 arrays. Also, x -= yDir * 5; should be y.

Comment: Add a `if(s == i) continue;` ? In order to not compare one enemy with itself ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will end up checking each enemy against itself.
Make your inner loop start from `s=i+1`